# Simple project won't compile

Tags: c++, winmain

I'm still having issues with an ongoing project that just won't compile. I've narrowed it down to the Includes but can't figure out what is going on. I've read that i need to add a WinMain entry point but that doesnt add up - I have classmates that didnt encounter this shit error at all.
So I've created a new empty project:

```
    #include <cstdlib> //include c library

    //using namespace std;
    //using namespace cv;

    namespace sp {
    int main() {
        return 0;
    }
    }
```

With the following includes:

Under GCC C++ Compiler Includes:

```
    C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\opencv\build\include
    C:\opencv_contrib-3.0.0\modules\xfeatures2d\include
```

Under MinGW C++ Linker Libraries:

```
    libopencv_core310
    libopencv_imgcodecs310
    libopencv_imgproc310
    libopencv_xfeatures2d310
    libopencv_features2d310
    libopencv_highgui310
```

Under MinGW C++ Linker Library search path:

```
    C:\Users\Amit\Desktop\opencv\build\x86\mingw\lib
```

Still, without calling any function from those libraries, I'm getting this error:

```
    09:45:43 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project testing ****
    Info: Internal Builder is used for build
    g++ "-IC:\\opencv_contrib-3.0.0\\modules\\xfeatures2d\\include" "-IC:\\Users\\Amit\\Desktop\\opencv\\build\\include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\testing.o" "..\\src\\testing.cpp" 
    g++ "-LC:\\Users\\Amit\\Desktop\\opencv\\build\\x86\\mingw\\lib" -o testing.exe "src\\testing.o" -llibopencv_core310 -llibopencv_imgcodecs310 -llibopencv_imgproc310 -llibopencv_xfeatures2d310 -llibopencv_features2d310 -llibopencv_highgui310 
    c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.9.3/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa7): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

    09:45:43 Build Finished (took 396ms)
```

Can anyone save me?

Thanks,
Amit.

Comment: Where do you define the entry point: *global* (not in namespace) `main()` function or `WinMain` function?

Comment: `main()` must reside in the global namespace.

Comment: Main can't be in a namespace because it has to be global (for the OS to call it).

Comment: @Wernerson `main()` (not used as entry point) can be in a namespace because the name is not reserved ([N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 3.6.1 Main function, paragraph 3)

Comment: If you don't want to create an entry point function, you should set the compiler to build a (static or dynamic) library.

Answer (score 2):

When you create an executable the linker expects a function named `main` in the global namespace. You have placed the function inside a namespace instead of the global namespace so the linker will not find it.

So either move your `main` outside of the `sp` namespace or tell the linker where the function is (at least that is possible with MS linker but not sure how it is done with g++).

Answer (score 2):

```
namespace sp {
    int main() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

declares an `sp::main` function, not `main`. This leaves you without a `main` function to serve as the program entry point.

Solution: Remove main from the `sp` namespace.

```
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```